# ElasticSearch for directory listings, how to search head office and local branches

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a business directory that head office and local branches are separate listings, but they all share the same business names etc.

```
class Listing:
    name = ...
    address = ...
    parent = ForeignKey(Listing, null=True)
```

How do I prepare the index/document and search query so that if head office and branch listings both covered in the search, drop the branch listings and only return the head office, all performed in one ES query?

Comment: can show what exactly you have in models and associations.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled on to this link, seems to be able to solve the problem

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/parent-child-mapping.html